# Is it possible to pass an object as parameter from one Java program to another?

Tags: java

I have program that searches for object, and sends it to another program.

I need the whole object to be passed.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, via mechanisms supporting remote procedure calls, such as [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) and [JINI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jini) (now known as [Apache River](http://river.apache.org/)).

You can also provide the passed object's class definition to the other program, via a class server.

Answer (score 4):

If you really mean "another program" (vs another class), you'd need

- either [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#Java) it explicitly and pass it via a file (not efficient but program chaining is usual on *nix)
- or pass it via [Remote Procedure Call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). There are many solutions for this, like the old RMI. I personally like [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

Comment: I really mean another program

Answer (score 0):

If you are really want to pass object from one java process to another you have to serialize object and then send it over network.

There are a lot of ways to serialize java object. The first and the simplest one is to mark class as `implements Serializable` and use the java built-in serialization mechanism. You can also serialize object using XML, JSON or other formats. You choice may depend on other requirements to the system including the complexity of types you are going to send.

There are a lot of ways to send object over network as well. For example you can impement your own client-server pair using sockets. You can use web services as well.

I hope these tips will give you the first push to read more. Then you are welcome to ask more specific questions.